# When I try to sync my Gradle files I get an error

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, androidx

I am currently building a Flutter app and almost everything has gone okay so far until I started getting this error. I've searched all over the internet for a solution but I have not found anything that solved it for me.

When I try to sync my Gradle files I get an error:

```
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:
The project 'android' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.2 and sync project

The project 'android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

I cant press the "Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.2 and sync project" as that fails.

When i try to build my app i get this error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G973F in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\android\build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
  Command: C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

This is the project-lever build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the app-level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1.0.0'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.tab.tab_truth_true"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

The strange thing is that I don't have any Gradle settings, see image
[{LINK} this is my gradle settings, as you see, all I get is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S91fy.png)

I have tried to migrate to Android X but with no luck. I just says "no usages found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project level `build.gradle` there is a duplicate class path:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
}
```

Please delete the second occurrence outside the `buildscript` block and try to build again.